I am having error 400-bad request when pulling data into PowerBI
I was pulling data into PowerBI using the Azure Cost management data connector, however, I was able to see all the tables in the Navigator, but once I click on a particular table for it to load so that I can click on transform data, I am having the error below:
DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/download?api-version=2019-11-01&$filter=properties/usageStart+ge+'2023-09-01'+and+properties/usageStart+le+'2024-09-12'' (400): Bad Request
Details:
    DataSourceKind=AzureCostManagement
    DataSourcePath=Enrollment Number;xxxxxxxxxxxx
    DataSourceKind.2=Web
    DataSourcePath.2=https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/download
    Url=https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/xxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/download?api-version=2019-11-01&$filter=properties/usageStart+ge+'2023-09-01'+and+properties/usageStart+le+'2024-09-12'

I have tried editing the M query by removing the single quotes on the date using the Advanced editor, however, there is no avenue for the edit. I tried with another billing Id and I was able to import the data successfully. But this particular Id I am using presently is throwing error.
